# Why does my window border disappeared?

Tags: 11.10

When I use keyboard shortcut Alt+Space+X to maximize window, the window border always disappeared, and I can't handle it. So what's going on? How can I fix it?
My Ubuntu version is 11.10.
Thanks!

Comment: a screen-shot will be good for understanding the problem

Comment: And as a sidenote - I think you can press Alt + F10 for the same effect.

Comment: Try unity --reset on terminal

Answer (score 1):

Simply move your mouse to the top of your screen and the menu of your window appears.
In fact your window border is merged with the screen border and top menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alt + F3

Advanced -> Uncheck "No Borders"

Comment: A little more explanation will be helpful , since it will help many Future users not just the OP.